# selecting Multiple checkboxes in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, checkbox

I have the following code for multiple checkboxes..

```
 echo $this->Form->input('type', array('type' => 'select', 'multiple' => 'checkbox','options' => array(
                'client' => 'Client',
                'vendor' => 'Vendor',
                'employee' => 'Employee'
            )
         ));
```

when I select more than one option and submit the form the following error comes "Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'". I want to save the values of the checkboxes.

Comment: What's the code you use for saving the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode the resulting `array` from the multiple checkboxes as a `string` before saving it to the database.

In this case its probably simplest to `implode()` the array, but where data is more structured (ie. nested arrays, associative arrays) you could also use something like `json_encode()`.

```
var_dump($this->data);
/*
array
  'Model' => 
    array
      'type' => 
        array
          0 => string 'client' (length=6)
          1 => string 'vendor' (length=6)
*/

$this->data['Model']['type'] = implode(',', $this->data['Model']['type']);
var_dump($this->data);
/*
array
  'Model' => 
    array
      'type' => string 'client,vendor' (length=13)
*/
```

This will make it more difficult (and slower) to query the database as you are storing multiple values in a single column.

```
$this->Model->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'type LIKE' => '%vendor%'
    )
));
```

Comment: Are you kidding me!? That's just a really bad database normalization example! You really don't wanna do that, NEVER!!

Comment: Agreed - I did submit this answer with some reluctance, but it solves the OP's immediate problem (Unknown column 'Array'). The other answer attempts to guide the OP down the path of best practice.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to store some HABTM information. If that's the case, take a look at this tutorial: http://mrphp.com.au/code/working-habtm-form-data-cakephp.

If you need more help, we'll need to see some code like the Models and the controller code that saves the records.

Comment: Today I was looking for something similar. I have dozens for multiple select lists needed to be shown as checkboxes for which I dont want to create a table for each of them. I just wanted a the best way to store the values of multiple "checked" checkobxes for a field or rather field group. Yes field group can be the solution, for example creating different fields with a grouped suffix, for example, tbl_one_field, tbl_two_field, tbl_three_field etc.. But yes, the best answer is still awaited.